# How to click on link Automatically in Phone?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm using Twilio to send SMS and there is link in it. I want to open that link automatically in user's phone.

can anyone help me? I do not know how to do it?

Comment: I feel like forcing a link to be opened from an SMS isn't possible

Comment: you feel or you sure?

Comment: I am looking for a text/sms autoresponder, that can reply yes, and click a link, can you help me?

Comment: i have done the autoresponder part but i don't know how to click that link automatically

Comment: I'm 99.5% sure the user has to click the link, otherwise spammers would just make it so spam links are auto-opened on someone's phone?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. However devices, based on configuration may provide a link preview option.

[How do SMS and MMS URL Link Previews Work on Mobile Devices?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013199334-How-do-SMS-and-MMS-URL-Link-Previews-Work-on-Mobile-Devices-)

[iOS Link Previews: What SMS Marketers Need to Know](https://www.tatango.com/blog/ios-10-what-sms-marketers-need-to-know-and-do/)